Allow 2 subnets devices communicate together
Situation:
I have 2 routers at home office. Router A is connected to internet and it's my main router with IP such as 192.168.1.1
Router B WAN port is connected to Router A Lan port so its IP address is 192.168.1.2 but Router B clients have IP like 192.168.0.*
Router A (HUAWEI - HG8245W5) is connected to fiber and has no wifi features I want, while Router B (TP Link Archer 55) is used to connect Wifi devices (like phones) and also IOT devices (so wifi).
Issue:
Router A clients do not communicate with Router B clients and vice versa.
I know I could place both routers in the same subnet, but in this case I'm not able to connected to Router B web interface, as it would be a simple switch. Moreover in this case, wifi devices do not have anymore access to internet.

Why can't you connect to the admin page of router B?
